# "RNPieChart" was not found in the UIManager. (react-native-charts-wrapper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-charts-wrapper

I'm having an issue with `react-native-charts-wrapper`
I keep getting an error even on IOS and Android

```
ERROR: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNPieChart" was not found in the UIManager.
```

There is a closed issue on the library's GitHub Page but there is no real solution
https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/issues/382

Any help is appreciated